# ASP.NET authentication using unique numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I do not know what this is called.   I thought it was called 2-factor authentication but all references to that on the web refer to an email or PIN emailed to you to reset your password.

I'd like to have my ASP.NET MVC site require username/password *AND* some unique ever-changing number such as one from the iPhone's Authenticator app.  Like those little keychanges we used to have with numbers always changing?

I have not settled on an authentication method yet: Azure Active Directory or something custom.  I will have at most 10 users of this system, each with different "roles": Admin, Manager (RW) and User (R).  If you have an opinion here, please say it but my main question is the first paragraph.

Any help / pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Ed

Comment: I think it is still [Two-Factor Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_factor_authentication). Where the "second" factor refers to *something you have [physically]*. This is why email is not a really good example (because you only need to 'know' it's password) - but a RSA fob, 'authenticator' application (I believe these are based on unique random/crypto streams) and phone SMS are good examples.

Comment: Thanks.   I found RSA solutions... asking for pricing.  I guess it is a little confusing that the same term is used for different things.  Oh well.  Thanks for giving me the idea to check for "RSA"... made all the difference!